# Select rows from table and additional data form other table if exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a hard time figuring out how to write a query that selects all rows that matches certain conditions from one table and extends the rows with data from another table if there is data that matches another set of conditions.

Table: books

```
id
school
isbn
name
```

Table: orders

```
id
school
department
isbn
quantity
```

The query I have is:

```
SELECT orders.*, books.name FROM orders
LEFT JOIN books ON orders.isbn = books.isbn
WHERE orders.school = 1 AND orders.department = 2
      AND books.school = 1
```

Now, the problem is that if a school hasn't added their books, isbn and names into the books table I'd still like to have the orders.* data returned with books.name set to null or something similar. Now I get zero rows instead. Is there a way to do this with one query?

Comment: please post some sample data and desired output? there might be some problem with your condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
and books.school = 1
```

from the where clause to the from clause.

```
left join books on orders.isbn = books.isbn 
and books.school = 1
```

**Edit starts here**

for raheel who says it doesn't matter.  Using the world database that came with the MySQL I downloaded, this query

```
select c.name, city.name cityname
from country c left join city on c.code = city.countrycode
AND city.name = 'toronto'
order by cityname;
```

returns 239 rows.  This query:

```
select c.name, city.name cityname
from country c left join city on c.code = city.countrycode
WHERE city.name = 'toronto'
order by cityname;
```

returns 1 row.  I think it matters

Comment: from your world db example, what is the result of the query if you remove `AND city.name = 'toronto'` from the first query?

Comment: This works as intended! Thanks! Would you mind explaining a little bit more why?

Comment: @didierc, if I remove the and city.name = 'toronto', I get 1000 rows.  There are 239 rows in the country table.

Comment: @samuelf, I don't know all the theory but I do know that if you use the where clause to filter on a joined table, the join behaves as an inner join.